# can we change java variable value by using javascript in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Is it possible to change java variable value on some function by using javascript in JSP?

eg. If I have to change the value on onchange event in the select box. such as

```
  <select id="search-field" onchange="report(this.value)">

                  <option  value="a">a</option>
                  <option  value="b">b</option>
                   <option  value="b">a</option>
  </select>
------------------------------------- 
<%
String check = "";
%>


  function report(period) {

      if(period=="a") {
          alert('test'+period);
          <%
          check = "a";
          %>
      } else if(period=="b") {
          alert('test'+period);
          <%
          check = "b";
          %>
      } else if(period=="c") {
          alert('test'+period);
          <%
          check = "c";
          %>
      }
   }
```

is this possible?

Comment: You should use AJAX for this asynchronous task

Comment: JSP variable has life on the server side while the js code has life on the client side; the answer is NO

Comment: The key to answer your question is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.